# Disable power-off menu when screen is locked

Tags: lock-screens, samsung-galaxy-spica, power-options

I own a Samsung Spica GT-i5700, how can I disable the power-off menu when the phone is locked. I am running CM7.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is in [Cerberus Anti Theft](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lsdroid.cerberus&hl=en_GB) and also in some custom android Roms (Such as Exodous). It doesn't require root but like any anti-theft software there is a paid version as the free one is limited to 30 days. 
But you could try the [Smart Screen Protector App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nezdroid.lockscreenprotector&hl=en) which is also mentioned in one of the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it is possible with that ROM. What you can do is to change the button's task when phone is locked (like Activator on iOS). I think CM7 isn't supports this feature but you can simply find it by google it (button task changer or something like that).

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Smart Screen Protector application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nezdroid.lockscreenprotector&hl=en) from the play store. It claims to disable the lock key when the screen is locked even with the pin. Doesn't require a ROOT device

If it does not work then you  can increase the delay time as suggested by the app.

Answer (score 0):

The Xposed plugin PowerMenuPlus may. If you add A fake power button and lock description, it will stop you device being turned off while locked, and confuse those trying to turn it off.