# Securing power off menu options when phone screen is locked or customizing power-off menu options?

Tags: lock-screens, 4.4-kitkat, nexus-5, power-options

I am using Google Nexus 5 with stock 4.4 KitKat.

When the phone is in `locked state (locked with a standard PIN code, password or pattern)` and we long press power button, we get the power-off menu with options like Power-Off, Flight mode and Sound options (Mute, Vibrate and Sound)

I was wondering that whether we could secure/disable the power-off and flight mode option if the phone is `locked state` or is there any way to customize these menu options?

I looked in one of such question but didn't get the answer:
[Disable power-off menu when screen is locked](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37512/disable-power-off-menu-when-screen-is-locked)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this app. It does exactly what you want : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nezdroid.lockscreenprotector

Comment: This app did work but it flickers while popping up the power menu. Was just looking for any other app which serves the purpose but was not able to find. Hence, marking this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

The app [mentioned by Vishal](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/59771/16575) is not working with Kitkat 4.4.4. I'm using a module for the *Xposed Framework* mentioned on [this XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/xposed-advanced-power-menu-anti-theft-t2594642/page15), where you can download it from the [attachment](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=2813156&d=1403510927).