# Lollipop: secure lock screen menu options

Tags: lock-screens, nexus-5, 5.0-lollipop

This is just an extension of the previously asked [question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/58662/securing-power-off-menu-options-when-phone-screen-is-locked-or-customizing-power).

I have upgraded Google Nexus 5 with android 5.0.1 Lollipop.

We can toggle wifi, data, flight mode and other options from locked screen.

Is there any way to secure or customize which of these menu options should be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't.

There are several bug reports like [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79670) one. I'm using Android 5.1.1 right now and this security problem still exists. This "bug" makes the Android Device Manager useless if your device gets stolen.